# How do I force the the parser to match a content as an ID rather than a token?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar as the following (It's a partial view with only the relevant parts):

```
elem_course : INIT_ABSCISSA '=' expression;

expression
    : ID
    | INT_VALUE
    | '(' expression ')'
    | expression OPERATOR1 expression
    | expression OPERATOR2 expression
    ;

OPERATOR1 : '*' | '/' ;

OPERATOR2 : '+' | '-' ;

fragment
WORD : LETTER (LETTER | NUM | '_' )*;

ID : WORD;

fragment
NUM : [0-9];

fragment
LETTER : [a-zA-Z];

BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN : 'BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN';
```

And, I would like to match the following line :

```
INIT_ABSCISSA = 40 + BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN
```

But as BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN is a lexer token and even the rule states that I except and ID, the parser matchs the token and raise me the following error when parsing:

```
line 11:29 mismatched input 'BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN' expecting {'(', INT_VALUE, ID}
```

Is there a way to force the parser that it should match the content as an ID rather than a token?

Answer (score 1):

(Quick note: It's nice to abbreviate content in questions, but it really helps if it is functioning, stand-alone content that demonstrates your issue)

In this case, I've had to add the following lever rules to get this to generate, so I'm making some (probably legitimate) assumptions.

```
INT_VALUE:     [\-+]? NUM+;
INIT_ABSCISSA: 'INIT_ABSCISSA';
WS:            [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

I'm also going to have to assume that `BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN: 'BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN';` appears before your `ID` rule.  As posted your token stream is as follows and could not generate the error you show)

```
[@0,0:12='INIT_ABSCISSA',<ID>,1:0]
[@1,14:14='=',<'='>,1:14]
[@2,16:17='40',<INT_VALUE>,1:16]
[@3,19:19='+',<OPERATOR2>,1:19]
[@4,21:40='BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN',<ID>,1:21]
[@5,41:40='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:41]
```

If I reorder the lexer rules like this:

```
INIT_ABSCISSA: 'INIT_ABSCISSA';
BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN: 'BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN';

OPERATOR1: '*' | '/';

OPERATOR2: '+' | '-';

fragment WORD: LETTER (LETTER | NUM | '_')*;

ID: WORD;

fragment NUM: [0-9];

fragment LETTER: [a-zA-Z];

INT_VALUE:     [\-+]? NUM+;
WS:            [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

I can get your error message.

The lexer looks at you input stream of characters and attempts to match all lexer rules. To choose the token type, ANTLR will:

- select the rule that matches the longest stream of input characters
- If multiple Lever rules match the same sequence of input characters, then the rule that appears first will be used (that's why I had to re-order the rules to get your error.

---

With those assumptions, now to your question.

The short answer is "you can't".  The Lexer processes input and determines token types before the parser is involved in any way.  There is nothing you can do in parser rules to influence Token Type.

The parser, on the other hand starts with the start rule and then uses a recursive descent algorithm to attempt to match your token stream to parser rules.

You don't really give any idea what really guides whether `BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN` should be a `BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN` or an `ID`, so I'll put an example together that assumes that it's an `ID` if it's on the right hand side (`rhs`) of the `elemen_course` rule.

Then this grammar:

```
grammar IDG
    ;

elem_course: INIT_ABSCISSA '=' rhs_expression;

rhs_expression
    : id = (ID | BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN | INIT_ABSCISSA)
    | INT_VALUE
    | '(' rhs_expression ')'
    | rhs_expression OPERATOR1 rhs_expression
    | rhs_expression OPERATOR2 rhs_expression
    ;
INIT_ABSCISSA:        'INIT_ABSCISSA';
BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN: 'BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN';

OPERATOR1: '*' | '/';
OPERATOR2: '+' | '-';

fragment WORD: LETTER (LETTER | NUM | '_')*;

ID: WORD;

fragment NUM: [0-9];

fragment LETTER: [a-zA-Z];

INT_VALUE: [\-+]? NUM+;
WS:        [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

produces this token stream and parse tree:

```
 $ grun  IDG elem_course -tokens -tree IDG.txt
[@0,0:12='INIT_ABSCISSA',<'INIT_ABSCISSA'>,1:0]
[@1,14:14='=',<'='>,1:14]
[@2,16:17='40',<INT_VALUE>,1:16]
[@3,19:19='+',<OPERATOR2>,1:19]
[@4,21:40='BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN',<'BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN'>,1:21]
[@5,41:40='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:41]
(elem_course INIT_ABSCISSA = (rhs_expression (rhs_expression 40) + (rhs_expression BEACON_ANTENNA_TRAIN)))
```

As a side note: It's *possible* that, depending on what drives your decision, you might be able to leverage Lexer modes, but there's not anything in your example to leaves that impression.

Comment: Thank you for your time and sorry I tried to be sharp and the question. So as Mike Lischke said I must add the tokens in a specific rule that can be used as ID to match them to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is the well known keyword-as-identifier problem and Mike Cargal gave you a working solution. I just want to add that the general approach for this problem is to add all keywords to a parser id rule that should be matched as an id. To restrict which keyword is allowed in certain grammar positions, you can use multiple id rules. For example the [MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mike-lischke/mysql-shell-plugins/blob/master/gui/frontend/src/parsing/mysql/MySQLParser.g4#L4550) uses this approach to a large extend to define keywords that can go as identifier in general or only as a label, for role names etc.